# Xcode and Scala

Tags: xcode, scala, textmate

Is there a way that I can make Xcode understand Scala's syntax through a plugin or something else? How about TextMate? Is there a bundle for that? I've seen quite a few Scala bundles for TextMate but not sure which one is "official" from the Scala comunity, or even if there is one. My first choice would be Xcode, TextMate second. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems to be possible. Check https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/tree/master/tool-support/src/xcode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there ever will be Scala for Xcode. I've started with TextMate first - get GetBundles, filter through "scala" bundles and find the most recent one coming from github and install it. It was fine for couple of months.

Out out interest, I then switched to IntelliJIdea (currently 10.5.2) with Scala plugin (latest version) and would never go back to TM. It's just that good. I'd highly recommend going the same way. Also tried NetBeans and Eclipse, but both are rubbish in terms of Scala support - compared to IntelliJ. Btw - don't forget the SBT plugin support. Very nice integration inside of the IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: OK I tried both TextMate and IntelliJ and I can see how IntelliJ is clearly superior. I did like the simplicity in TextMate however. Thank you for this information.